# add attribute to an existing kobject

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev

I'm working on porting a driver I've written for the 2.6.x kernel series into 3.x (i.e. RH EL 6 -> RH EL 7).  My driver solution actually comes in two modules: a modified form of ahci.c (from the kernel tree) and my own upper-layer character driver for access AHCI registers and even executing commands against the drive.

In porting to CentOS 7, I've run into an interesting problem.  Changes to the drivers I'm building on remove the access to the scsi_host attributes in SYSFS.  My question then is, can I append attributes onto devices already existing in SYSFS?  Every example I've come across shows making the attributes at the point of device creation, e.g.:

```c
static ssize_t port_show(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr,
                         char *buff);
static struct kobj_attribute pxclb_attr = __ATTR(pxclb, 0664, port_show, NULL);
static struct attribute *attrs[] = {
    &pxclb_attr.attr,
    NULL,
};

static struct attribute_group port_group = {
    .attrs = attrs,
};

/* much other code */

sysfs_create_group(&kobj, &port_group);
```

This example comes from my character driver.  All the searches I've done with Google, and referencing my Linux Foundation Drivers class book, all show attribute creation done at the time of device creation.  Can I add to them at any time?  It would seem that one could call `sysfs_create_group()` at any time.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `attribute` in sysfs at anytime you like.

The reason that almost all the drivers add `attribute` in `probe` is that userspace has strict expectations on when attributes get created. When a new device is registered in the kernel, a uevent is generated to notify userspace (like udev) that a new device is available. If attributes are added after the device is registered, then userspace won't get notified and userspace will not know about the new attributes.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see the importance of adding attributes at that time only.  Thank you for the explanation.  I had thought that it was possible/fine but knew there might be more to it.